# Select statement where Users.ID=Forum.ID

Tags: mysql, mongodb, select, database

Is it possible to select a document in MongoDB where one id equals the other? For example:

db.users Collection has the following Document

```
{ "_id" : 3, "username" : "abc", ..... }
```

and Collection db.forum has the following Document

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("52134f9fcbf7770b886a44a9"), "user_id" : 2, "link" : "http://website.tld", }
```

Now I want to select an entry where `**db.users._id = db.forum.user_id**`

Is this possible?

Thanks in advance

Comment: THERE ARE NO JOINS IN MONGODB

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to perform this operation within your application, MongoDB does not allow joins.

See the following two links for more information:

http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/data-modeling/

http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/model-embedded-one-to-many-relationships-between-documents/

What you'll want to do is query on the first document, get the id in your application, then query on your second document.  If this is a common use case for you then you should consider embedding your subdocument into the main document if possible.  Otherwise, MongoDB might not be the right tool for you; there's nothing wrong with using SQL if it's the right tool for the job.

Comment: Considering the scenario of a forum to a user and that this is 90% a one-to-many relation I do not think that this is viable as an embedded relationship.

Comment: Agree, in this case the join should probably just be done in the application layer

Comment: Thank you very much Mason. I'll try is this way